# Frontend instances frequently restart

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am developing a gaming application and I am currently facing a strange behavior with my F4 Frontend instances. They frequently restart at random interval time despite constantly under load. Sometimes they last 2 hours but sometimes they die just 30 mins after launch and players experience high latency during the cold start.

I have set up warmup requests, I have also tried to set up resident instances, pending latency, etc to at least avoid the latency due to the restarts but without success.

I have thought of memory leaks in the application, but the instances use only 200MB RAM before they die while F4 instances have 512. There are no signs of crashes in the logs as well.

I believe this is not a normal behavior of app engine instances. I would be thankful if you could help me identify the problem.

[Latency statistics](http://postimg.org/image/z0qdct7jp/)

[Logs](http://postimg.org/image/5uz1d1v23/)

Comment: I've found the loading latency for Java quite high compared to other runtimes and even with warmup requests, user requests can still be served by instances not yet ready.  You may want to consider isolating the relevant part of your application into a separate go/python module if you find the loading latency better.

Comment: Unfortunately I am currently experienced only with Java :( The loading latency wouldn't be a problem if it didn't occur like every 30mins. It means that every player entering the game would experience the lag at least once. I feel like something is causing the instances to behave like that but i cannot find what. I have not worked with other gae apps before so I am not sure which behavior is normal and which is not. Would you share the performance of your instances ?

Comment: [This other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40421496/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-why-instances-get-killed) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need one big instance, you may be better off running a few smaller instances instead.

If you do need all players to be on the same instance, you should probably switch to [manual scaling](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/#Java_Instance_scaling_and_class) from automatic scaling.

Comment: No, I dont need one instance. I am currently using automatic scaling

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue Nhat is reporting. We open a long ticket with GAE support and not answer yet. Also the problem with frequent restarting is the load balancer, because it sent requests to a fresh instance, then clients are stuck until instance boots up. No way to let load balancer something like: 'dont sent me request until I let you know I booted and I'm ready'.
I think the issue is a serious GAE infrastructure problem, this is the long short tale: due an issue with our app we was moved to an older GAE version and it seems we was running in an isolated farm. Then instances were running for hours without disruption, flawlessly. Once they move us again to the standard place, we face again the problem without any change in our side.
By now we haven't found a resolution and this is impacting a lot into overall system experience.